# Redirecting output from terminal to specific sheet in .csv file

Tags: bash, csv, redirect, terminal, output

I would like to redirect some output from the terminal to sheets in a spreadsheet. Is this possible within bash?

To be specific, I have generated some output that is displayed in the terminal. I have managed to redirect this output instead to a sheet within a .csv file as follows:

`COMMAND awk '{print $1,$2}' > FILE.csv`

The `$1,$2` redirects columns 1 and 2 of the terminal output to a sheet within FILE.csv.

a) Is it possible to specify which sheet the output is redirected to? That is, how to modify the above command so that the output is instead redirected to, say, sheet 25 of FILE.csv?

b) The `$` denotes columns of the terminal output to be outputted to the .csv file. What is the syntax to output, say, column 1 row 2 only to the .csv file?

EDIT

The terminal output is of the form

`X1, Y1 
 X2, Y2
 ...`

consisting of around 1000 lines and I would like to copy the `Xi` values to, say, column B in a .csv file and the `Yi` values to column C.

I have many such outputs all generated separately so in general I'd like to have them all next to each other in a single .csv file. That is to say, the above output could go in columns B and C and then another such output can go in Columns D and E etc...

Comment: CSV files only contain a single sheet. In fact, the CSV definition does not even know about the _sheet_ concept

Comment: @Poshi Thank you for the comment. I see. Actually I had tried first with .xlsx but for some reason I could then not open this so tried with .csv. Do you know the syntax to instead redirect the output to a certain column within a .csv file?

Comment: @CAF that's because xlsx is actually an archive (just like zip) with an XML file that defines the structure of the document. Migrate to python, which probably has a library for it.

Comment: @Bayou Thanks. For my purposes, actually it may be fine to redirect the terminal output to a certain column within the .csv file. Is this possible by way of modification of the command in my OP?

Comment: Would be possible with `sed`, but you'll have to write a little regexp. Without any input and expected output added to your question I will not be able to help you with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Linux you can achieve this using [paste](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/paste/):

```
paste -d "," <(COMMAND1 | awk '{print $1","$2}') \
  <(COMMAND2 | awk '{print $1","$2}') \
  (more COMMANDs...) \
> FILE.csv
```

Of course, this only works if all COMMANDs output the same number of rows.

If that's not the case, you can use [join](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/join/) to merge the files by a matching identifier column.

Comment: Since Mac OS is based on Unix, many of these basic command line tools exist in both worlds. Just type `paste` in the terminal to check if the command exists.

Comment: paste -d "," <(COMMAND1 | awk '{print $1","$2}') > file.csv

Comment: What is `COMMAND` in this case?

Comment: COMMAND is ./a.out SOMETHING... actually I managed now to get some output to the .csv but doesn't your command always write to columns 1 and 2? (via $1, $2)

Comment: yes, each individual `<(COMMAND | awk '{print $1","$2}')` prints two columns, but `paste` combines them column-wise into a more broad table. For that you have to use two or more instances of the `COMMAND`. Probably it's best in your case to collect the output of each `COMMAND` in a file and run `paste -d "," ...` on all of the output files.

Comment: Thank you. And, just out of interest, is it possible to print out only select rows as well? i.e the above with columns 1 and 2 but now say I wanted to print out just row 25 or something (corresponding to `X_25, y_25`)

Comment: Sure, you mean for the joint output, right? You can just insert `| sed -ne '25p'` before the `> FILE.csv`. `| awk 'NR==25'` works as well,

Comment: Thank you very much. Last thing I am curious about is, if you know, as I have many COMMANDs to iterate over, is there an approach in which I may loop over the commands by insertion of a for loop? E.g.  currently I have `<(COMMAND 1 | awk '{print $1","$2}')<(COMMAND 2 | awk '{print $1","$2}') ... <(COMMAND 1000 | awk '{print $1","$2}') | sed -ne '1,400 p' > file.csv. ` I'd like to instead produce a for loop so that I can concatenate all these commands: something like (pseudocode) `for i from 1 to 1000 <(COMMAND i | awk '{print $1","$2}') | sed -ne '1,400 p' > file.csv. `Is it easy?

Comment: In that case I would use a loop to create the output for each command, and then `paste` them together. Assuming that `a.out` produces TAB-separated output, you can use `tr` to replace TABs with commas: 1. `for i in {1..1000}; do COMMAND $i | tr "\t" "," > output_$i.csv; done`, 2. `paste -d "," output_*.csv > joint_output.csv`.

Comment: Thank you. There is the strange peculiarity that while the pasting to each of the output_i.csv files is going as expected, the pasting to the common joint_output.csv is not. For some reason, the contents of output_1.csv is pasted first then output_10.csv next to it then output_100.csv then output_11.csv... I don't see how this can be understood from your piece of code?

Comment: Oh yeah, this has to do with the sorting order of file names. To preserve the desired ordering, use this command: `paste -d "," output_{1..1000}.csv > joint_output.csv`